# Tibco JDBC Update dry run

Tags: tibco, tibco-designer

Is it possible to have a dry run in Tibco for the JDBC Update activities? Meaning that I want to run those activities, but not actually update the database.

Even running in test mode if it's possible will be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way. I haven't tested it yet, but theoretically it should work.

The solution is to install [P6Spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy) and to create a custom [module](http://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configandusage.html#modulelist) that will throw an exception when trying to execute an INSERT/UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

The only option I see is having a copy of the targeted tables in a separe schema, duplicate the data, and temporary align the JDBC connection of you activity on this secondary, temporary/test database.

Since you can use global variables, no code is changed between test and delivery (a typical goal), and you can compare both DB tables to see if the WOULD HAVE ran well...

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the activity into a transaction group and rollback whenever you only want to test the statement. Otherwise just exit the group normally so the data gets commited.